# How to build column with dynamic title?

Tags: java, dynamic-reports

I'm trying to use DynamicReport report generation and I want build column with dynamic title.

I have the following structure of data:

```
class Data {

private String date;
private String status;
```

and I'm build column like:

```
col.column("Status", "status", type.stringType())
```

but I want to set title dynamically. Something like this:

```
List<Data> items = generate();

report()
.columns(
    // ...
    col.column(dateItem.getDate(), "status", type.stringType())
)
.setDataSource(items)
// ...
```

Any advice?

---

**UPD1**:
The problem is that report will be filled dynamically:

```
report().setDataSource(items)
```

and I have no access to each item.

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: Where are the items and what are they? Please be specific.

Comment: @Dante see updated example

Comment: You mean you want to access date and status of each item that is in the list?

Comment: Please post entire code and then tell me the exact problem. Right now I am going blind as you say that you have a list of items and at the same time you say you cannot access the items. Also please reply to my first comment.

Comment: @Dante yes. I can fill column value dynamically with DynamicReports api but I want to fill title dynamically as well.

Comment: @Dante have you ever use DynamicReports?